# MySQL row ordering doesn't make sense

Tags: mysql, sorting, mysql-workbench

So, I have a standard products table with varchar(255) `name` field. What puzzles me is when the name field is sorted, as the Workbench screenshot below shows, the '&' character is valued higher than the '-'.

[image]

I've isolated the characters to ensure there wasn't any other mystery symbols messing up the sorting. Not the case.

Would someone please enlighten me on this? The ASCII value of '&' is **38** whereas '-'s is **45**. So id 3212 should be first. I'm really curious as to what is going on here.

MySQL: *Ver 8.0.26*

Table Collation: *utf8mb4_unicode_ci*

Engine: *InnoDB*

Comment: Since the names are identical up to the "-" and "&", does it sort properly if you do a : ORDER BY name DESC

Comment: Hey ihatzi, thank you for the answer. Yes, the full column sort was there initially. The substr was done for debugging/"display (for a lack of a better word atm)" purposes.

Comment: Ah, makes sense now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, unicode sort order is different from ASCII sort order.

Since multiple languages might use the same unicode symbols to represent different characters, each language needs to implement character sorting differently.

So they fall back on using the [Unicode Collation Algorithm](https://unicode.org/reports/tr10/).

These links might help you to understand more about why this is sorting the way it is, albeit, it'll probably take a lot more effort for you to change the sort order (if that's what you're trying to do).

https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/01/know-your-sort-orders/

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html#charset-unicode-sets-collating-weights

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just give me a while to read through all of those then I'll accept it.

Comment: The PERL link is especially nice. I'm glad I ran into this issue. Cheers man.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to check:

```
mysql> SELECT '&' > '-' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
+--------------------------------------+
| '&' > '-' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------------------+
|                                    1 |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT '&' > '-' COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
+-------------------------------+
| '&' > '-' COLLATE utf8mb4_bin |
+-------------------------------+
|                             0 |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you really wanted to compare the hex, be sure to use some collation ending in `_bin`.

Comment: Thank you. While reading your answer I'm reminded of another strange anomaly I've encountered on the products table in the question. It has SKU varchar(16) column that, when used normally (as in `... where sku = 'abc123'`) with strings functions fine. But, introducing a variable gives: `Error Code: 1267. Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='` Using variables on any other column works fine. Using your method when setting the variable `set @sku = 'ABO01FB' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;` solves the issue nicely.

Comment: Database collations seems to be a damned rabbit hole ;)

Comment: Yes, a rabbit hole.  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'col%';`